# Plesk 11.5.30 Windows Crashes after upgrade with Internal Error redirect plesk.phtml

Tags: windows, email, plesk, horde

I upgraded Plesk to 11.5.30 and after upgrade when I visited the control panel and tried to edit an email address, I received the following error:

=========================================================

Internal error: script 'redirect/plesk.phtml' not found in path (C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk/admin/common/views/scripts/;C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk/admin/smb/application/views/scripts/;./views\scripts/)
Message     script 'redirect/plesk.phtml' not found in path (C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk/admin/common/views/scripts/;C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk/admin/smb/application/views/scripts/;./views\scripts/)
File    Abstract.php
Line    988

## Type    Zend_View_Exception

Definitely, plesk.phtml is missing in the redirect folder under C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk/admin/smb/application/views/scripts/.

Then i clicked on Website Scripting and Security under the domain name in control panel and then found the following error:

=========================================================
 Internal error: script 'web/settings.phtml' not found in path (C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk/admin/common/views/scripts/;C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk/admin/smb/application/views/scripts/;./views\scripts/)
Message     script 'web/settings.phtml' not found in path (C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk/admin/common/views/scripts/;C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk/admin/smb/application/views/scripts/;./views\scripts/)
File    Abstract.php
Line    988

## Type    Zend_View_Exception

Definitely, settings.phtml is missing under web folder in C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk/admin/smb/application/views/scripts/

If anyone has experienced this issue or has an idea to resolve it please let me know and I shall be very thankful to you for your assistance.

Thank you in advance for reading it

Comment: If you won't to submit ticket to Parallels support, you can create thread on Paralles forum and provide server access to parallels guys because It's absolutely impossible to debug such issues at StackOverflow.

Comment: Just to try, you can find and delete microupdates.xml in c:\ParallelsInstaller, run ai.exe and install some component. In 99% it doesn't helps.